# Time produces weird results with leading sudo call

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time, sudo

If I run time without sudo

```
$ time python test_file_cmp.py

real    31m5.439s
user    1m31.057s
sys 4m51.030s
```

With sudo

```
$ sudo time python test_file_cmp.py 
[sudo] password for user: 
92.13user 299.38system 30:41.26elapsed 21%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6172maxresident)k
237041856inputs+221771216outputs (0major+54789minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` is a shell builtin. When you write `sudo time ...` that invokes the executable `time` on your `$PATH` (`/usr/bin/time`, perhaps) rather than the builtin.

Try `time sudo ...` or `sudo sh -c 'time python ...'` instead.

Comment: Side question, how can I tell if a command is a shell builtin?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins with the `type` builtin command (e.g. `type time`).